# How to display a list of all files including hidden files in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, directory-listing

I am writing a bash script in Debian and I want it to show all files including the hidden ones in the home directory. I would usually use `ls -a` but with the script in the bin directory it is only showing files in that.

What command would I use to get it to show ones from other directories?

Answer (score 1):

`ls -a ~` will show the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Will you can still use ls -a :

```
ls -a $HOME
```

Replace $HOME with the directory you want.

Comment: Users' home directories may not be in /home. It would be safer to use $HOME.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ls -a $(pwd)
```

the pwd variable stores the name of the working directory

Comment: This will show all the files in the current directory, whereas the OP wants to see files in his home directory.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you can also list all files in the your home directory with:

```
ls -al $HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -al -- "$HOME"
```

This works in some older shells as well, it works even if `$HOME` contains whitespace, and even if `$HOME` starts with a dash (quite unlikely, but possible).

If you want the filenames only, then use `-l` instead of `-al`.

Answer (score -2):

The command prints to list of all files including hidden files in the home directory.

```
ls -a $HOME
```

`ls` means list of all files

`cd ..` represents to hidden files

`$` used for substitution

`HOME` represents to the directory at start